# `server-start` hook?

Tags: hooks, emacsclient, server, emacs-daemon

Is there a hook to execute stuff after I've run `emacs --daemon`? I'd like to keep load stuff **only** when running `emacs --daemon` and **not** when running `emacs`.

I know it sounds like using square wheels, but I do have my reasons.

Comment: You could make the relevant portions of your init file conditional on `(daemonp)`.

Comment: Related to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28431/how-know-if-emacs-is-being-initialized-in-daemon-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the relevant portions of you init file in a conditional
on `(daemonp)`, whose docstring reads:

> Return non-`nil` if the current emacs process is a daemon.
>   If the daemon was given a name argument, return that name.

So:

```
(when (daemonp)
  (do-server-only-stuff-here))
```

Comment: Note however that this is not equivalent to a `server-start` hook: that code won't run if `server-start` is used without using `--daemon`.