# How to check for emacs being initialized in daemon mode?

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs, emacs-daemon

I use emacs gui in daemon mode and also in standalone terminal mode. There is a package that I just want to use when I'm using emacs in terminal mode.

the problem is that I can't use `(display-graphic-p)` because when I run `emacs --daemon` the initialization system thinks that I have no graphic-display, but I'll have when I connect the emacsclient to the daemon.

I wish I had access to a function like this:

```
(if (emacs-initiating-in-daemon-mode)
    (my-setup-for-gui)
    (my-setup-for-terminal))
```

Is that possible?

Comment: When started in daemon mode, you may later open up a tty frame (i.e. use emacsclient from a terminal), so your daemon should be prepared for *both* GUI and text-terminal frames *at the same time*.  How to do that depends on the details of what you want/need to do, which you haven't provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `daemonp` is what you're looking for.  From its docstring:

```
Return non-nil if the current emacs process is a daemon.
If the daemon was given a name argument, return that name.
```